# VBA Copy/Paste Alternatives - Charts Flash/Flicker

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, events, copy-paste

Would like to try another way to copy/paste data from one worksheet to another. I've read the `.copy` and `.paste` script is inefficient and slow. I believe this is why my charts in another worksheet keep flickering/flashing to the point of not being able to read them.

The script below is triggered every couple milliseconds due to the `Worksheet Calculate` event and then copying from my dashboard to the log and incrementing to the next row every time the event is triggered for another copy/paste iteration. When the script is finished running it could have up to 60,000 rows of data copied over from dashboard. Script works great just the chart flashing makes it hard to interpret.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

On Error GoTo SafeExit
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
    Set cpyRng = sht1.Range("A3:M3")
    Set rngLogTargetBeginningCell = sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Set rngLastCellSelection = Selection

    cpyRng.Copy
    rngLogTargetBeginningCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    rngLastCellSelection.Select
    
End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: try disabling "rngLastCellSelection.Select". This line has no effect at all. But can contribute to the annoying flickering. Is the chart pointing to some of these ranges involved on this copy/paste operation?

Comment: If the reality of your context is that this procedure is the only one that adds data to the `Log` sheet then you could further improve performance by storing the destination row number in a public variable and simply increment it by 1 in the body of the procedure; in doing so you could avoid both the 'reading' of the sheet to determine the last row, and the `Offset` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an alternate approach which doesn't use the clipboard?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Not Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A3:M3")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp). _
               Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your logic work perfectly. This what I was looking for. Fast and efficient.

Comment: Why use `with`? It's not needed there at all.

Comment: The last term ".Value" on the line makes use of the With statement.

Comment: @Cameron Critchlow `.Rows.Count`, `.Columns.Count`, `.Value` reference therange to be copied. Without `With` - `End With` the range should be repeatedly used...

Comment: Ah. Good point @FaneDuru. It would be a very long line. I guess I didn't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I usually do, and for me works fine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
        Sheets("Dashboard").UsedRange.Copy Sheets("Log").Range("A3") 'Informe where starts the data you want to copy
        Sheets("Log").UsedRange.Copy
        Sheets("Log").UsedRange.PastSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    End If
    
    SafeExit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```